# Is there any method to detect color in flutter?

Tags: machine-learning, flutter, artificial-intelligence

I'm using Flutter.

I want to detect and count the place where a specific color occurs via a phone camera.

For example, I have a picture as below:

[image]

I move the phone's camera over the picture, it will show the result like 3 red, 2 blue.

How can I do it by flutter?

Thanks in advance!!!